# 'System.StackOverflowException' in EntityFramework.dll without code reference or stacktrace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, stack-overflow

While other questions here on SO always seem to be able to pinpoint which statement causes the StackOverflow Error; my VS gives no code reference.

```
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
```

But there is no stacktrace; I just get:

```
[External Code] 
The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.
```

No idea where it thrashes; any ideas how I can get Visual Studio 2015 to give me more information? When I click continue, the process just exits.

```
The program '[13224] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

Any additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there isnt an error being output to the Windows EventViewer?

Comment: @MasterYoda I'm afraid not.

Comment: @DavidG: Seriously? I am asking if there is a way for visual studio to show me a stacktrace or offending line; anything (maybe with some EntityFramework symbols or something; I don't know, that's why I ask here.

Comment: @NKCSS not likely, a stack overflow exception effectively trashes the stack, making parts (or all) of it unavailable.  To solve this, I recommend logging the crap out of your application and stepping through it until the problem is encountered.  These kinds of bugs are difficult to solve.

Comment: Have you tried setting Break when thrown for System.StackOverflowException while debugging?

Comment: Bisection FTW! Put a breakpoint. If you hit it, move it further. If you don't, move it closer!

Comment: @Tipx Indeed, basic debugging is far more efficient than posting a question on here with very little useful information attached.

Comment: The process where this occurs spans several thousend lines of code in a process that runs over an hour; there is no way you could step through it, as it occurs something like 50 minutes in :-/ Normally, when you hit a stackoverflowexception in your own code, the full stack is visible; but since this is triggereed from external code; it's not (think it's on a seprate thread as well, which is probably the reason there is no entry point in my own code). Just wondered if there was anything else I could do to get more info out of the box; thanks anyway though/